# Primefaces on IBM WAS 8.5 doesn't works

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, websphere-8

I'm trying to use primefaces-4.0 with the IBM Websphere application server v 8.5.0.2. The problem is, that server doesn't proceed xhtml page. It renders only the `<h:...>` tags.

here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>DELTA.TRANS</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.JSP_UPDATE_CHECK</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.LOAD_FACES_CONFIG_AT_STARTUP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>
    *.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>
    /faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list></web-app>
```

here is my page to render

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"><h:head>
<title>Дельта::Транслітерація</title>
<h:outputStylesheet id="style" library="css" name="style.css" /></h:head><f:view contentType="text/html" locale="ru">

<h:body>
    <div id="main-center" class="main-center">
        <p:panel header="Транслітерація" footer="© Дельта Банк, 2013">
            <h:form id="form">
                <h3>Український текст</h3>
                <p:inputTextarea id="uaText" value="#{translitBean.uaString}" rows="5" style="width:99%" />
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <div class="setup">Налаштування:</div>
                    <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{translitBean.options}">  
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Без змін" itemValue="1" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Всі великі" itemValue="2" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Всі маленькі" itemValue="3" />
                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Виконати..." update="display" id="ajax" actionListener="#{translitBean.doTranslit}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" icon="ui-icon-shuffle"/>
                <br />
                <h3>Транслітерація</h3>
                <div class="trans">
                    <h:outputText id="display" value="#{translitBean.enString}" />
                </div>
            </h:form>
            <h:outputLink value="http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/55-2010-%D0%BF" target="_blank" class="link">Постанова №55. Про впорядкування транслітерації українського алфавіту латиницею</h:outputLink> 
        </p:panel>
    </div>
</h:body></f:view></html>
```

and i get the same page.

UPD.

if i'm adding

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in the web.xml the application is not responding and i'm having a big error log, which consists of one repeting error:

```
[28.01.14 9:30:09:084 EET] 00000b16 lifecycle     E   JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: /index.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@c1845262]
[28.01.14 9:30:09:086 EET] 00000b16 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [Faces Servlet] in application [DELTA.TRANS]. Exception created : [java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:162)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:162)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:162)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:975)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

to

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.faces</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it didn't helped me. The situation didn't changed.

Comment: you are welcome. using your web.xml and your page on my glassfish 4 works, maybe your WAS installation has some problem. check if there is an older jsf lib in runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

During several test i've discovered that the problem doesn't relates to the primefaces at all. The JSF modules on server doesn't work with the simplest xhtml pages. It is my fault - I haven't tested them first, and now I'm on my way to google the solution.

By the way, I have installed a new server instance, added primefaces-4.0.jar to the WEB-INF/lib and marked it for export. Everything worked just as planed on the basic server configuration, without editing Shared Lib and classloader.